# Pourquoi « le plus souvent seuls sur leur ordinateur» ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, verbes

J'ai une question sur la nature d'une expression lue dans l'Express.

> 43 % des garçons et 34 % des filles. La moitié consomment ces images à tout moment, le plus souvent seuls sur leur ordinateur

Pourquoi utilise-t-on « seuls » au lieu de « seul » ? Est-ce parce que c’est une nouvelle phrase ?

Je comprends que cela fait référence aux garçons et aux filles, mais même dans une nouvelle phrase ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'adjectif **seul** pourrait techniquement s'accorder avec **la moitié**, mais dans ce cas, il faudrait écrire :

> La moitié **consomme** ces images **seule** sur **son** ordinateur

mais c'est difficilement acceptable puisque la moitié en question n'a pas **un** seul ordinateur.

La variante :

> ...**seule** sur **ses ordinateurs**

est encore moins vraisemblable.

L'auteur de l'article a choisi de considérer *la moitié* comme un singulier ayant un sens pluriel et donc d'accorder *seul* avec « 43 % des garçons et 34 % des filles » d'où les pluriels ***consomment*** et ***seuls*** qui rendent bien le grand nombre d'enfants en question.

L'accord de ***leur ordinateur*** peut aussi poser problème. Le pluriel devrait être utilisé, c'est à dire :

> ...le plus souvent seuls sur **leurs ordinateurs**

puisqu'il y a autant d'ordinateurs que d'enfants mais l'auteur à préféré le singulier pour insister sur la solitude de chaque enfant et pour ne pas laisser penser que les enfants disposent chacun de plusieurs ordinateurs.

Answer (score 2):

Comme vous avez compris, l'adjectif **seuls** s'accorde avec **garçons et filles** de la phrase précédente.

C'est au *masculin pluriel* parce que **garçons et filles** est au *pluriel* et que **garçons** est *masculin*.

Son apparition dans une *nouvelle phrase* n'influe pas sur son accord. En fait, ce sont les noms que l'adjectif qualifie qui le déterminent.

La phrase peut être expliquée par

> Chacun des garçons et chacune des filles consomme seul ces images.

Comment: Il manque une proposition subordonnée à la première phrase ou alors, il faut supprimer *que*. *...garçons est masculin*, pas *en masculin*. *...ne décide rien de son accord* →  *...n'influe pas sur son accord*. *C'est les noms auquels l'adjectif se rapporte décident*→  *Ce sont les noms que l'adjectif qualifie qui le déterminent*. *Chacun entre ces garçons et filles consomme les images seul* →  *Chacun des garçons et chacune des filles consomme seul ces images*

Comment: Merci @jlliagre pour les corrections de grammaire !

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est pas parce que c'est une nouvelle phrase. Ici, "la moitié" fait référence à un groupe de jeunes, donc c'est un pluriel.

On peut simplifier la phrase comme ça :

> Ils consomment des images seuls devant leur ordinateur

Ici, il **faut** mettre "seul" au pluriel, car le sujet est pluriel, l'adjectif s'applique à tous les enfants (comme on dirait "*Ils sont grands*", "*Ils sont jeunes*", etc.).

---

À noter qu'on peut aussi être seul "à plusieurs", par exemple si tu prends le métro avec des amis et que la rame est complètement vide, tu peux dire :

> On est tout seuls !

Answer (score 0):

On peut considérer que `la moitié` est suivi de `[d'entre eux]`, sous-entendu car sans ambiguïté dans le contexte ; le reste de la phrase s'accorde alors normalement avec `eux`.